# Moving a file between cloud providers

Tags: java, file, cloud, inputstream, move

I want to move a file from a cloud provider to another one by using their Java APIs.

On the source cloud provider I can get a file as input stream or alternatively it can downloaded to a File object (using a File Output Stream). The target cloud provider accepts a file to store as input stream (needs content length) or as File object.

Is it better to move a file by

- getting the input stream and content length of the file on the cloud storage provider and using these data to store on the target cloud provider or
- downloading the file on the source cloud provider to an File object first, before it will be stored on the target cloud provider.

What are the advantages / disadvantages?

A advantage of the first moving strategy is it's needs less disk space. But are they any performance differences?

Comment: I've voted to close this question. I really don't see how it can be answered without in depth knowledge of how the two cloud providers operate. At best, we will just get the subjective opinions of SO users without any supporting facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a File object, unless you know the files you're transferring will fit in memory. Use streaming. You can still store the file locally before sending it to the target provider.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the file contents in memory, by using a stream-copy approach, is likely to be marginally more performant since you're not occurring disk-bound I/O wait. That said, network time for traffic to/from the cloud storage APIs is probably going to be your main bottleneck so it's unlikely to make a critical difference.

A possible advantage of writing the files to disk is that you get an automatic extra backup of everything, and may have a simpler basis for performing retries if an upload fails.